# RStudio is damaged and cant be opened for MacOS High Sierra (version 10.13.6)

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I tried downloading Rstudio-1.4.1717.dmg (macOS 10.13+) for my macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.6), I was able to download it and have it in the application but when I tried opening the RStudio from my application, the verifying toolbox with waiting bar will appear and finally it would say "RStudio is damaged and can't be opened. you should move it to the Trash".
I have tried re-downloading the RStudio multiple times and have also removed/uninstalled the old Rstudio download from the trash. I have tried restarting the computer multiple times, I have also tried updating my computer system But nothing has worked out with opening RStudio.

Please send help on how to troubleshoot issues with damaged RStudio in macOS 10.13.6.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: have you considered updating to BigSur

Comment: You may want to install a legacy version of Rstudio or update your OS. I run this version of Rstudio just fine on my macOS 10.15 Catalina

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use an older version of Rstudio. Go to this site https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/

Your should be able to install **RStudio Desktop 1.3.1093** on 10.13.6

Comment: The oldest version I could find on rstudio.com was [2021.09.1](https://dailies.rstudio.com/version/2021.09.1+372.pro1/), which didn't work for me (macOS 10.13.6), however I found a [download of 1.1.463](http://download1.rstudio.org/RStudio-1.1.463.dmg) which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can open any version (included new) using High Sierra 10.13+ without install RStudio, just running by mounted volume. But if you install, you need install the compatible version.

**High Sierra 10.13+** supports `RStudio Desktop 1.3.1093 - "Apricot Nasturtium".`

```
RStudio Desktop - Platform Support (MacOS)
Based From Older Versions: rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/

Version        MacOS     Arch       
0.98.1103      10.6+     x86, x64
0.99.903       10.6+     x86, x64
1.0.153        10.6+     x86, x64
1.1.463        10.6+     x86, x64
1.2.5042       10.11+    x64
1.3.1093       10.13+    x64
1.4.1106       10.14+    x64
```